# Horizontal scroll div within flex

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get a horizontal scroll on the links container, within the right pane as shown in the code snippet, but for some reason the scroll is not showing up there and the whole page becomes scrollable. Also, the left and the right pane should have the same width (`flex: 1` for both). Any ideas what I am missing here?

```css
#parent {
  display: flex;
}

#left_pane {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: red;
}

#right_pane {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: yellow;
}

#links_container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    overflow-x: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.mylink {
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #F4F6F8;
}
```

```html
<div id='parent'>
  <div id='left_pane'>
    <p>hey</p>
  </div>
  <div id='right_pane'>
      <div id='links_container'>
        <a href="" class='mylink'>Link1</a>
        <a href="" class='mylink'>Link1</a>
        <a href="" class='mylink'>Link1</a>
        <a href="" class='mylink'>Link1</a>
        <a href="" class='mylink'>Link1</a>
        <a href="" class='mylink'>Link1</a>
        <a href="" class='mylink'>Link1</a>
        <a href="" class='mylink'>Link1</a>
        <a href="" class='mylink'>Link1</a>
        <a href="" class='mylink'>Link1</a>
        <a href="" class='mylink'>Link1</a>
        <a href="" class='mylink'>Link1</a>
        <a href="" class='mylink'>Link1</a>
        <a href="" class='mylink'>Link1</a>
        <a href="" class='mylink'>Link1</a>
        <a href="" class='mylink'>Link1</a>
        <a href="" class='mylink'>Link1</a>
        <a href="" class='mylink'>Link1</a>
        <a href="" class='mylink'>Link1</a>
        <a href="" class='mylink'>Link1</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: on a side note, for some reason, the top padding of the links is shaved off too :(

Comment: check my updated answer

Comment: first duplicate to understand the min-width:0 trick, second one for the padding

Comment: @TemaniAfif I searched for like 30 mins before posting and also browsed the suggested "related questions", so I guess there's an issue with that. Sorry for not finding them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `min-width` on `#right_pane`

For `padding`
Add `display: inline-block;` on `a` tag

```
#right_pane {
    flex: 1;
    background-color: yellow;
    min-width: 5px;
}
```

```css
#parent {
  display: flex;
}

#left_pane {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: red;
}

#right_pane {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: yellow;
  min-width: 5px;
}

#links_container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    overflow-x: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.mylink {
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #F4F6F8;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id='parent'>
  <div id='left_pane'>
    <p>hey</p>
  </div>
  <div id='right_pane'>
      <div id='links_container'>
        <a href="" class='mylink'>Link1</a>
        <a href="" class='mylink'>Link1</a>
        <a href="" class='mylink'>Link1</a>
        <a href="" class='mylink'>Link1</a>
        <a href="" class='mylink'>Link1</a>
        <a href="" class='mylink'>Link1</a>
        <a href="" class='mylink'>Link1</a>
        <a href="" class='mylink'>Link1</a>
        <a href="" class='mylink'>Link1</a>
        <a href="" class='mylink'>Link1</a>
        <a href="" class='mylink'>Link1</a>
        <a href="" class='mylink'>Link1</a>
        <a href="" class='mylink'>Link1</a>
        <a href="" class='mylink'>Link1</a>
        <a href="" class='mylink'>Link1</a>
        <a href="" class='mylink'>Link1</a>
        <a href="" class='mylink'>Link1</a>
        <a href="" class='mylink'>Link1</a>
        <a href="" class='mylink'>Link1</a>
        <a href="" class='mylink'>Link1</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: wow! thanks! is that a bug or is there an explanation for this?